# Como separar o titulo e o conteudo em html?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Meu teste </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style> 
        #titulo {
            background-color: blue;
            position:fixed;
        }

        </style>
</head>
<body>


  <h1 id="titulo"> Meu titulo </h1>


  <div id="conteudo">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse quis velit a libero pretium fringilla in vel eros. Fusce vitae metus sit amet nisi consectetur semper. Duis et sem vitae dolor iaculis eleifend in vel lorem. Morbi egestas blandit turpis, dignissim vulputate metus eleifend non. Phasellus consequat erat eget justo ullamcorper, eu accumsan lacus facilisis. Donec hendrerit non nibh scelerisque aliquam. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam posuere massa ac porttitor aliquam. Vivamus tempus nibh mi. Duis eros erat, fringilla vitae ligula quis, mollis laoreet diam. Quisque tempus dolor in risus vehicula interdum. Sed suscipit leo a sagittis pellentesque. Nunc sed vulputate dolor. Proin convallis iaculis condimentum. Suspendisse finibus feugiat nisl sollicitudin dapibus. Nunc euismod, felis ut cursus scelerisque, lectus lorem sollicitudin nunc, vel posuere diam erat eget leo. </p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Eu estava querendo criar um menu que move junto com a página quando navegamos pelo site movendo com o mouse, porém, ao adicionar o position:fixed o conteúdo fica dentro do titulo. Como faço para deixar tudo em ordem,tipo, o titulo lá em cima, e o conteudo em baixo sem uma ficar entrando dentro da outra? Qual tag utilizo?

Comment: Já cogitou colocar `margin-top` no elemento do conteúdo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro, você precisa configurar o menu (#titulo) para ficar no topo e também na camada mais alta das tags (de uma lida sobre [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index)). Depois precisa adicionar um espaço no topo do `<body>` para deixar o texto "aparecer" quando abrir o seu site, ele pode ter a altura maior ou igual a altura do seu `#titulo`.

Eu já sofri bastante com esse tipo de estilo, costumam chamar de [sticky header css](https://css-tricks.com/scroll-fix-content/).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Meu teste </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    #titulo {
      background-color: blue;
      position: fixed;
      
      /** posicionando o titulo no topo **/
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      height: 40px;
      /** posicionando na camada mais alta **/
      z-index: 999;
      /** adicionando estilos **/
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    body {
      /** padding da mesma altura, ou maior que o titulo **/
      padding-top: 50px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="titulo"> Meu titulo </h1>
  <div id="conteudo">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse quis velit a libero pretium fringilla in vel eros. Fusce vitae metus sit amet nisi consectetur semper. Duis et sem vitae dolor iaculis eleifend in vel lorem. Morbi egestas blandit
      turpis, dignissim vulputate metus eleifend non. Phasellus consequat erat eget justo ullamcorper, eu accumsan lacus facilisis. Donec hendrerit non nibh scelerisque aliquam. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames
      ac turpis egestas. Nullam posuere massa ac porttitor aliquam. Vivamus tempus nibh mi. Duis eros erat, fringilla vitae ligula quis, mollis laoreet diam. Quisque tempus dolor in risus vehicula interdum. Sed suscipit leo a sagittis pellentesque. Nunc
      sed vulputate dolor. Proin convallis iaculis condimentum. Suspendisse finibus feugiat nisl sollicitudin dapibus. Nunc euismod, felis ut cursus scelerisque, lectus lorem sollicitudin nunc, vel posuere diam erat eget leo. </p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado man :D

Answer (score 1):

Aí é preciso adicionar vários estilos, tanto no título quando na página:

```css
html, body{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

#titulo {
   background-color: blue;
   position:fixed;
   display: block;
   width:100%;
   margin: 0;
}
#conteudo{
 padding-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="titulo"> Meu titulo </h1>

<div id="conteudo">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse quis velit a libero pretium fringilla in vel eros. Fusce vitae metus sit amet nisi consectetur semper. Duis et sem vitae dolor iaculis eleifend in vel lorem. Morbi egestas blandit turpis, dignissim vulputate metus eleifend non. Phasellus consequat erat eget justo ullamcorper, eu accumsan lacus facilisis. Donec hendrerit non nibh scelerisque aliquam. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam posuere massa ac porttitor aliquam. Vivamus tempus nibh mi. Duis eros erat, fringilla vitae ligula quis, mollis laoreet diam. Quisque tempus dolor in risus vehicula interdum. Sed suscipit leo a sagittis pellentesque. Nunc sed vulputate dolor. Proin convallis iaculis condimentum. Suspendisse finibus feugiat nisl sollicitudin dapibus. Nunc euismod, felis ut cursus scelerisque, lectus lorem sollicitudin nunc, vel posuere diam erat eget leo. </p>
   <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
</div>
```

O `padding-top` pode variar de acordo com a altura esperada do seu título.

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer separar de cima é so colocar (html):

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Meu teste </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style> 
        #titulo {
            margin-top: (a sua escolha);
            background-color: blue;
            position:fixed;
        }

        </style>
</head>
<body>


  <h1 id="titulo"> Meu titulo </h1>


  <div id="conteudo">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse quis velit a libero pretium fringilla in vel eros. Fusce vitae metus sit amet nisi consectetur semper. Duis et sem vitae dolor iaculis eleifend in vel lorem. Morbi egestas blandit turpis, dignissim vulputate metus eleifend non. Phasellus consequat erat eget justo ullamcorper, eu accumsan lacus facilisis. Donec hendrerit non nibh scelerisque aliquam. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam posuere massa ac porttitor aliquam. Vivamus tempus nibh mi. Duis eros erat, fringilla vitae ligula quis, mollis laoreet diam. Quisque tempus dolor in risus vehicula interdum. Sed suscipit leo a sagittis pellentesque. Nunc sed vulputate dolor. Proin convallis iaculis condimentum. Suspendisse finibus feugiat nisl sollicitudin dapibus. Nunc euismod, felis ut cursus scelerisque, lectus lorem sollicitudin nunc, vel posuere diam erat eget leo. </p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

E pronto mais se quiser em outros lados so colocar margin-left(para esquerda), margin-bottom(pra baixo) e margin-right(pra direita).